# Filestream File Share does not allow files to be created

Tags: filestream

When attempting to create a file or folder in a SQL filestream file share, Windows presents the following dialog:

[image: filestream error]

For those who cannot see the image, the error reads "The file 'New Text Document.txt' is too large for the destination file system."

The create filetable script is as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ARITHABORT ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Media] AS FILETABLE ON [DboData] FILESTREAM_ON [FileStreamData]
WITH
(
FILETABLE_DIRECTORY = N'ShareName', FILETABLE_COLLATE_FILENAME =     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)
GO
```

This is a newly created filetable and I am unaware how to troubleshoot it.  Google returns almost no relevant results.

EDIT: As it turns out, files greater than 0 bytes can be copied into the filetable without error, but renaming the file still causes the above error.

EDIT2: The error occurs whenever a file is moved.  Create and Delete is successful.